# How do I search Debian packages by description?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, search

I wanted to find packages related to `transmission`, a BitTorrent client but couldn't find how to search package descriptions.

Why do this?

In certain cases, package names are not obvious; for instance a remote controll application for Transmission can be named `transmission-remote-gtk` (an older one) or `transgui` (more recent). The description of both packages includes *transmission* though. It would be practical to the non-*aware* user that I am, who expects other packages to have non-obvious names if there was a way to lookup package description instead.

On my system `aptitude search` looks up into package names only. On the other hand there's `eix -S` under Gentoo.

So how would I search packages by description under Debian? (I guess I can browse all available packages and `grep` the results. I expect a more appropriate method, of course hence my question.)

---

**EDIT**: Listing results by built-in commands `aptitude` and `apt-cache`

As suggested by [Marco](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227046/86969) and [MatthewRock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227044/86969) there's `aptitude search '~d<string>'` and `apt-get search`. However the two appear to also include results that have nothing to do with the search string (on my system at least):

```
# aptitude search '~dtransmission'
p   atlc                          - calculateur de lignes de transmission arbitraires                  
p   atlc:i386                     - calculateur de lignes de transmission arbitraires                  
p   atlc-examples                 - Exemples pour le calculateur de transmission de ligne arbitraire   
p   between                       - game about consciousness and isolation  
p   between:i386                  - game about consciousness and isolation  
p   boinc-app-seti                - SETI@home application for the BOINC client                         
p   boinc-app-seti:i386           - SETI@home application for the BOINC client                         
p   boinc-app-seti-dbg            - debug symbols for SETI@home             
p   boinc-app-seti-dbg:i386       - debug symbols for SETI@home             
p   boinc-app-seti-graphics       - SETI@home application for the BOINC client (with graphics)         
p   boinc-app-seti-graphics:i386  - SETI@home application for the BOINC client (with graphics)         
p   ca-cacert                     - CAcert.org root certificates            
p   cstream                       - general-purpose stream-handling tool similar to dd                 
p   cstream:i386                  - general-purpose stream-handling tool similar to dd                 
p   cycle                         - programme de calendrier pour femme      
...
```

with `aptitude` or

```
# apt-cache search transmission
between - game about consciousness and isolation
boinc-app-seti - SETI@home application for the BOINC client
boinc-app-seti-dbg - debug symbols for SETI@home
boinc-app-seti-graphics - SETI@home application for the BOINC client (with graphics)
ca-cacert - CAcert.org root certificates
libcollada2gltfconvert-dev - COLLDADA to glTF conversion library -- development
cstream - general-purpose stream-handling tool similar to dd
freedv - Software Defined Radio (SDR)
glfer - program for reception and transmission of QRSS/DFCW signals
libgmetric4j-java - gmetric4j Ganglia metric transmission API
libgnuradio-noaa3.7.5 - gnuradio noaa satellite signals functions
hamfax - Receive/send radio facsimile transmissions with Soundcard/PTC-II
hylafax-server - Flexible client/server fax software - server daemons
hylafax-server-dbg - Debug symbols for the hylafax server
libijs-dev - IJS raster image transport protocol: development files
libijs-doc - IJS raster image transport protocol: documentation
ike-scan - discover and fingerprint IKE hosts (IPsec VPN Servers)
ion - NASA implementation of Delay-Tolerant Networking (DTN)
ion-doc - Interplanetary Overlay Network - examples and documentation
libion-dev - NASA implementation of Delay-Tolerant Networking (DTN) - development files
...
```

with `apt-cache`. The above even includes results which do not match "transmission" nor "trans". Weird indeed.

Comment: They do match; the search is on the *fully* description, not just the one-line summary. E.g., `apt-cache show between` gives a several paragraph description of between, including the line *These things that appear are ugly and non-procedural: indecipherable **transmissions** bubbling up through static,…* Personally I use `apt-cache search transmission | grep -i transmission` to solve this problem. Not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Damn'it! That's all but obvious :-D . Isn't there a Debian idiom that distinguishes between what is picked by "~d" and the single line printed by `aptitude` that would limit searching to only the latter part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache search packagename
```

This shows packages that apt considers related(many of them don't even include name of packge in both description and name).

If you only want packages that contain packagename in description or name, pipe with grep:

```
apt-cache search packagename | grep 'packagename'
```

**BUT!** Other tools for the rescue:

```
axi-cache search packagename
```

[You can read more about axi-cache here](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.apt-cache.html). `axi-cache` sorts scores by relevance and shows you percentage of match, so it's more likely to give you the output you want. Looks like my new replacement for `apt-cache`.

`axi-cache` is part of [apt-xapian package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+package/apt-xapian-index)

Comment: Right. Strangely enough `apt-cache search` returns far more than those packages with the search expression in either the package name or description. It also lists packages neither of which name or description match. I guess that's where `grep` comes to the rescue. This is a strange behaviour though.

Comment: @Nasha check out my update. Found new tool that is really better.

Comment: Good! I used to prefer `aptitude` over `apt-xxx` and extras ... so far. Looks like a few additional tools doesn't hurt.

Comment: Unfortunately `axi-cache` is not available under my Linux Mint version (Petra, 16). I'll keep it in mind by all means however!

Comment: @Nasha see my edit. If you looked for axi-cache in your package manager, you might have failed, but it's in different package(and actually on my Ubuntu installation it is already installed)

Comment: @Nasha and according to [this link](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/apt-xapian-index) you should have this in repository

Comment: Woops! Turns out that package was *already* installed :-D . And it's definitely what I was looking for as it also sorts results by ranking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aptitude` with the `~d` argument to search in the descriptions:

```
aptitude search '~d <string>' # e.g.
aptitude search '~d torrent'  # search for “torrent” in the description
```

Comment: Thanks for the `aptitude` hint. Strangely enough, just like `apt-cache search` I also get results which have nothing to do with transmission. And the off-topic results are not even the same between the two :-D.

Comment: The search command doesn't search for relation with a given package but for the given string in the description. Please provide an example if you think it produces false results.

Comment: I can understand. But what about `p gpstrans:i386 - communicate with a Garmin Global Positioning System receiver` or `p gap-trans-groups Database of transitive groups for GAP` then? There are many other examples like this while I was searching for `transmission`, not just `trans`, which would make more sense.

Comment: `aptitude search '~d transmission' | grep gpstrans` doesn't return anything on my system. I can't reproduce your problem with the provided information.

Comment: Then I deduce it's probably my own system (cache) that's become corrupt or so. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't believe there's an issue with your cache. But I notice that you have a localized system. You can try to search the english description with `LANG=C aptitude search …` and check if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The answer *is* `apt-cache search transmission`. It does return only packages whose description contains the specified substring. (Not necessarily the specified word, for example the command also matches “retransmission”.)

The string might not appear in the output of `apt-cache search transmission` because that only prints the first line of the description, whereas the search includes the whole description. To print full descriptions, run `apt-cache --full search transmission`.